# Using a function's return value in itself over and over again?

Tags: python, return, infinite

I'm not sure how to accomplish this, but I'm trying to use a function's return value over and over by only having to pass in one initial value into the function rather than having to manually input the new value. Is this possible in python? 3 is the initial value, and 4 is the return value of that function. I want to be able to pass in '4' without having to do print(test2(4)) to achieve the next value, rather I want to just be able to get 3, 4, 5, 6 by being able to use the previous return value from the function.

````
def test(n):
  return n + 1

def test2(n):
  return test(n)


num = 3
while(True):
  print(test2(num))

#num = 3
#num = 4 - 1st iteration
#num = 5 - 2nd iteration 
#num = 6 - 3rd iteration, and so on..```
````

Comment: Are those 4 lines of comment the desired effect? You could assign `num = test2(num)` in the `while` loop (and then add `print(num)` to see the results).

Comment: I don't think I'm exactly grasping what you are trying to do here, but I think you may want to use a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Comment: what is the break condition? Are you asking about recursive functions?

Comment: I've updated with a bit more info on what I want to do.. I don't think it's necessarily a recursion. Yes, those lines are the desired affect. I just don't want to have to use the next value manually in the function, I just want to have it continue using the previous return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in @hymnsfordisco's answer, this sounds a lot like a generator or an object (initialization + state).

```
def test(initial):
    x = initial
    while True:
        yield x
        x += 1

nums = test(5)
for v in nums:
    print v
    if v > 6:
      break
```

gives

```
5
6
7
```

if you want it as a function instead of a loop:

```
func = test(5).next

func() # -> 5
func() # -> 6
func() # -> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it! Thanks to Seb. I'm still not 100% sure how it works... New to python!

````
num = 3

while(True):
  num = test2(num)
  print(num)
  sleep(3)```
````